# How to handle Too much redirect with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to parse a site, but I encountered a `Too much redirect` exception.
Here is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
HtmlPage homePage = null;
String url = "http://www.freelake.org/pages/Freetown-Lakeville_RSD/Departments/Director_of_Financial_Operatio";
try {
    client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(30000);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    homePage = client.getPage(url);
    synchronized (homePage) {
        homePage.wait(25000);
    }
    System.out.println(homePage.asXml());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception are mention below

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: Too much redirect for http://www.freelake.org/resolver/2345183424.20480.0000/route.00/pages/Freetown-Lakeville_RSD/Departments/Director_of_Financial_Operatio
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1353)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1371)
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because HtmlUnit caches the response, and there is redirection to another page then returning back.

I tested with the below, and it works:

```
client.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but I am doing this through Selenium. In Selenium you cannot get access to the [WebClient](http://seleniumhq.github.io/htmlunit-driver/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html) directly, because it is `protected`.

I worked around it like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true) {
    {
        this.getWebClient().getCache().setMaxSize(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The page http://www.freelake.org/pages/Freetown-Lakeville_RSD/Departments/Director_of_Financial_Operatio sends 2 redirects:

1. http://www.freelake.org/GroupHome.page, then to
2. http://www.freelake.org/pages/Freetown-Lakeville_RSD/Departments/Director_of_Financial_Operatio

Use the 2nd url and it should work. Or look for a way to tell the library to allow a certain amount of redirects; 2 in this case.

Edit: This might help. Don't use this library myself:

```
client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. yes i have used 2nd URL and i have enabled redirection but still i am getting same exception